# Determine Node Module size

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there any any possible way wherein the npm modules size can be determined pre / post installation. e.g. npm request --size

I have to find the size of request vs https module of node.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As npm modules are nothing but a bundle of javascript for the installed modules.What will you do of size?

Comment: I have a requirement to compare the size between request and https module. We will go with the light weighted module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm view <pkg_name>
```

This gives you information like `fileCount` and `unpackedSize`. [Refer documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view)

To view the `unpackedSize` only, you can use

```
npm view <pkg_name> dist.unpackedSize
```

The size here is in bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I received the output but a bit confused that the size is bytes or Kilobytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [howfat](https://github.com/megahertz/howfat) which displays size of a package together with children dependencies.

```
$ npx howfat --no-human-readable request
Dependencies: 17
Size: 3821422
Files: 678
```